# Remove redundant space after scaling in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to produce a layout in Jetpack compose, where I have to scale the content of a `Box`. But I've noticed that after being scaled, the `Box` is still surrounded with empty space, enough to put unscaled content. I need to get rid of that space, without applying any modifiers to the content of the `Box`

```
@Composable
fun Power() {
    Row {
        Box(
            Modifier
                .background(Color.Green)) {
           Text("a")
        }
        Box(
            Modifier.scale(0.5f)
                .background(Color.Yellow)) {
            Text("bbbb")
        }
    }
}
```

Expectations:

[image]

Reality:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A `box` is redundant here, just keep the `fontSize` of the *second* text lower than the `fontSize` of the *first* text in the row ( tweak with the text size to achieve proper size instead of using `scaling` )

Try this:-

```
Row(Modifier.background(Color.White), verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
    Text("a", Modifier.background(Color.Green).padding(0.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp, 6.dp), fontSize = 30.sp, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
    Text("bbbb", Modifier.background(Color.Yellow), fontSize = 16.sp)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, I think I didn't describe the problem clearly. The thing is that those are not usual Text elements I'm rendering, those are meant to be custom composables (in fact I'm providing mathematical equation rendering, kind of ms word equation). That's why I woild prefer scaling. Anyway, using fontSize parameter is a good idea, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Adjust **offset** according to your need

```
@Composable
fun Power() {
    Row {
        Box(
            Modifier
                .background(Color.Green)) {
           Text("a")
        }
        Box(
            Modifier.scale(0.5f).offset(-10.dp, 0.dp)
                .background(Color.Yellow)) {
            Text("bbbb")
        }
    }
}
```